# Bond Futures Invoice Price vs Futures Price

Tags: bonds, financial-derivatives

If I buy a bond Futures I have to pay the current Futures Price but at settlement day I pay the invoice price(=settlement price on position day*conversion factor + accrued interest) which is actually different from the futures price? What are the actual cashflows for the long position of such a contract?